# How to groupby with certain condition in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, sum

I have dataframe like this

```
    A   B
0   1   a
1   2   a
2   3   b
3   4   b
4   5   a
```

I want to get result below(1row*4column dataframe),

```
A_count_all means the number of rows in dataframe   df.A.count()

A_sum_all means the df.A.sum()

A_count_a is df.loc[df.B==a,"A"].count()

A_sum_a is df.loc[df.B==a,"A"].sum()


    A_count_all   A_sum_all  A_count_a   A_sum_a  
0      5            15          3            8
```

how can I get this result dataframe?

Comment: actually,I could get each elements value,,but I had no idea how to reconstruct dataframe.. but I could learn thanks to answer. But I should have posted what I tried. I will be careful next time. thank you for reply.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) constructor:

```
A_count_all = df.A.count()
A_sum_all = df.A.sum()
A_count_a = df.loc[df.B=='a',"A"].count()
A_sum_a = df.loc[df.B=='a',"A"].sum()

print (pd.DataFrame({'A_count_all':A_count_all, 
                     'A_sum_all':A_sum_all,
                     'A_count_a':A_count_a,
                     'A_sum_a':A_sum_a},
                      index=[0],
                      columns=['A_count_all','A_sum_all','A_count_a','A_sum_a']))

   A_count_all  A_sum_all  A_count_a  A_sum_a
0            5         15          3        8
```

Thank you [`Kris`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332665/how-to-groupby-with-certain-condition-in-pandas-dataframe/39332727?noredirect=1#comment65997064_39332727) for another solution:

```
print (pd.DataFrame(data=[[df.A.count(),
                          df.A.sum(),
                          df.loc[df.B=='a',"A"].count(),
                          df.loc[df.B=='a',"A"].sum()]],
                          columns=['A_count_all','A_sum_all','A_count_a','A_sum_a']))

   A_count_all  A_sum_all  A_count_a  A_sum_a
0            5         15          3        8
```

Comment: Or do it in one go: `pd.DataFrame(data=[[df.A.count(),df.A.sum(),df.loc[df.B=='a',"A"].count(),df.loc[df.B=='a',"A"].sum()]],columns=["A_count_all","A_sum_all","A_count_a","A_sum_a"])`

Comment: Thank you, i add it to answer.